# Python DomainError: there is no ring associated with RR

Tags: python, integrate, piecewise

When I run this code:

```
from __future__ import division
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')   
y = sp.symbols('y')

pw1 = sp.Piecewise((sp.exp(t/y), 1 <= t), (0, True))
pw2 = sp.Piecewise((2.5*t, sp.And((t >= 0), (t < 5))), (0, True))

xonInt = sp.integrate (pw1*pw2, t)
print xonInt
```

I get the error (full error message is in the end of this question):

> raise DomainError('there is no ring associated with %s' % self)
>   sympy.polys.polyerrors.DomainError: there is no ring associated with RR

Interestingly, when I change the line

```
pw2 = sp.Piecewise((2.5*t, sp.And((t >= 0), (t < 5))), (0, True))
```

to

```
pw2 = sp.Piecewise((2*t,   sp.And((t >= 0), (t < 5))), (0, True))
```

or the line

```
pw1 = sp.Piecewise((sp.exp(t/y), 1 <= t), (0, True))
```

to

```
pw1 = sp.Piecewise((sp.exp(t/5), 1 <= t), (0, True))
```

the code runs correctly without errors.

What does this error mean? How can I correct my code?

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "IntegralTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    xonInt = sp.integrate (pw1*pw2, t)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/utilities/decorator.py",    line 35, in threaded_func
    return func(expr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1232, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 487, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 740, in _eval_integral
    return f._eval_integral(x)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/piecewise.py", line 200, in _eval_integral
    return self.func(*[(integrate(e, x), c) for e, c in self.args])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/utilities/decorator.py", line 35, in threaded_func
    return func(expr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1232, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 487, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 740, in _eval_integral
    return f._eval_integral(x)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/piecewise.py", line 200, in _eval_integral
    return self.func(*[(integrate(e, x), c) for e, c in self.args])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/utilities/decorator.py", line 35, in threaded_func
    return func(expr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1232, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 487, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 754, in _eval_integral
    result, i = risch_integrate(f, x, separate_integral=True, conds=conds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 1678, in risch_integrate
    ans, i, b = integrate_hyperexponential(fa, fd, DE, conds=conds)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 1408, in integrate_hyperexponential
    g1, h, r = hermite_reduce(a, d, DE)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 964, in hermite_reduce
    fp, fs, fn = canonical_representation(a, d, DE)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 944, in canonical_representation
    dn, ds = splitfactor(d, DE)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 869, in splitfactor
    Dp = derivation(p, DE, coefficientD=coefficientD)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/risch.py", line 824, in derivation
    r += (d*pv.diff(v)).as_poly(t)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/decorators.py", line 77, in _sympifyit_wrapper
    return func(a, b)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 3865, in _mul__
    return f.mul(g)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 1350, in mul
    _, per, F, G = f._unify(g)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 358, in _unify
    dom, lev = f.rep.dom.unify(g.rep.dom, gens), len(gens) - 1
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py", line 250, in unify
    return K0.unify_with_symbols(K1, symbols)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py", line 230, in unify_with_symbols
    return K0.unify(K1)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py", line 274, in unify
    domain = domain.get_ring()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/domains/realfield.py", line 106, in get_ring
raise DomainError('there is no ring associated with %s' % self)
sympy.polys.polyerrors.DomainError: there is no ring associated with RR
```